# Is it possible to access any Azure Function trigger details/context in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a few azure functions, they're in a .net core project which has a startup.cs class in which I register all of the dependencies.

This is all works fine, but I'd like some way of calling a common method regardless of which trigger was invoked. But within that method I'd like to access details from some sort of context (?) to know which azure function's being called.

This is based on the assumption that Startup.cs is called every time a function is.

### What I've Tried

I'm aware of the `FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute` but this is currently only in preview mode so I'm not permitted to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access any Azure Function trigger details/context in Startup.cs?

In short, it's **impossible**.

You will not be able to get the `ExecutionContext` in startup. Because the `ExecutionContext` enables interaction with the Azure Functions execution environment when a function call is made.

However, in your function startup, your Azure Function is not yet processing an actual function call.